# how to check if values from a database column exist based on another tables column

Tags: mysql

How I can check if the value from a column does exist on another column, if exist echo it one by one. I don't have code for now except for the DB connection because I really don't know how to start.

I have two tables, like table1 has only four to five numbers which will be the basis of table number 2, which has a lot of numbers. Now, if the number exist on table number 2 based on the values on table number1. I want to echo or print all those numbers.

```
table1. 
number  code_name  
1201    cheza
1303    butter
1404    onion

table2. 
Code
1201
1201
1050
1030
1303
soon.
```

Can I just do a single MySQL query and get those values on an array? Two arrays may be and compare? is that possible?

Comment: Perhaps a join like inner join?

Comment: please try to clarify the question more succinctly to define what you are trying to do to get better responses.  It sounds like your `table 2` is just a list of `foreign keys` where you want to go look up and print the data for said keys from `table 1`

Answer (score 0):

If there's a common trait shared among the tables you're working with, then you can do a join on that column and have everything in one array. You would need to do something like:

```
SELECT *  
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.code = t2.code
```

Comment: That could work, but I need to show also the values on code_name column. If its 1201 and exist echo also the corresponding value in code_anme.

Comment: It's a bit tough to understand the schema you've presented above. Perhaps sharing with us your table structure using `SHOW CREATE TABLE` would help us better understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Every one, I would like you to know that I do appreciate your response.  Thank you!.. 

please see my table below:

Comment: Table1
field: code
Type : Int

Table 2. 
field : Code and Name
        int      varchar

Comment: sorry I did not mean to post the table field and type like that.  it seems its not showing correctly